# Why does "what is my IP" not match what I see in my Apache logs?

Tags: networking, ip

Just trying to get a better feel for how things work. I'm currently tethered to my phone and when I do a search on Google for what is my IP I get one public IP address, we'll call it A here, registered to AT&T in the Maryland area as expected.

What is strange though is that I was doing work on my Azure cloud and set up a rule to block any connections not coming from A. The rule failed so I removed the rule, hit my Apache server on Azure, checked the logs and got a completely different public address B also registered to AT&T in the Maryland area.

I double checked what is my IP and it's still showing IP A. I set up a rule to instead only allow connections from IP B and everything works great. How is it that a what is my IP site sees A but my Apache server sees a separate public IP address B (which, again, is also registered to AT&T so it's not like this is some weird Azure voodoo).

Note: All IPs are IPv4.

Comment: I'm not sure how we could give you useful information with just the information given in your question. We could guess randomly, I suppose. I'll randomly guess that Google supports IPv6 but that you are entering an IPv4 address for Azure, so A is your public IPv6 address and B is your public IPv4 address.

Comment: You would be able to know if there's something I misunderstand about how IP networking works on the data plan for phones or perhaps . Since the implication wasn't clear I added a caveat that everything involved is IPv4. This isn't an "I don't understand basic networking question". I'm looking for someone that maybe has insight in this specific situation.

Comment: The only information you give us about your specific situation is that you're using Azure and that you're tethered to your phone. You don't even tell us whether your phone is connected by WiFi or cell and you don't tell us anything about the two public IP addresses (are they in the same city? are they both customer endpoint addresses?). So unless you happen to find someone who happens to have stumbled onto this same situation *in precisely the same way*, all you'll get are guesses., Even people who were in this same situation won't know it because of the lack of details.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm not in a rush, maybe someone has stumbled into this specific situation. I don't expect you personally to answer this question. I'm happy to wait to see if someone else knows.

Comment: I updated my question to include locality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cell phone ISP is using carrier-grade NAT. This is true almost anywhere in the world except if you pay for special IoT/business services.

While a carrier-grade NAT system does work somewhat like your home router, it typically has multiple public IP addresses assigned and will try to balance the load between them. The specifics of the load balancing algorithm vary, but one simple key could be (source IP, destination IP). Azure isn’t Google, so your communication ended up being translated to a different public IP address.

---

This is also why firewall rules like “allow traffic only from *1.1.1.1*” only work if *1.1.1.1* is actually a static IP address. Even without carrier-grade NAT, your IP address on a non-business Cable/DSL connection could change at any time.